# What is the equivalent of git squash in perforce (p4)

Tags: git, version-control, perforce

In git, I find the **squash** or **fixup** very useful while rebasing local commits. Consider the below scenario.

- Commit "Feature", "Partial Bug Fix", "Complete Bug fix" are three separate local commits.
- While doing *git rebase --interactive*, I *squash* those commits into one commit "Complete Feature"

I am looking for something similar in perforce (or p4v interface). I am aware of shelving/unshelving. Any possible workarounds?

Comment: Are you already using the `p4v` interface?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, I have a p4v interface.

Comment: Typically with Perforce you don't have *local* commits.  Just as it would be bad practice to squash non-local commits in git, it doesn't make much sense to squash already-submitted Perforce changes except in some uncommon scenarios where you happen to have administrative access to the Perforce server.

Answer (score 3):

Use `p4 unsubmit` to unsubmit the changes, then `p4 resubmit -i` to resubmit them in interactive mode (which I believe allows you to squash/etc).

Since `unsubmit` converts the submitted changes into normal shelved changes you can operate on them with other commands as well.

Comment: Late followon -- what I would consider to be the standard Perforce workflow here would be to do your work in a development branch (that's your "local commits"), and then to decide how to finalize your changes when you merge back to the mainline.  The default for a merge is to do everything in one changelist, which is effectively a squash (but only from the point of view of the mainline; the individual changes stay where they are in your dev branch).